# ASP.NET Overloaded method on Foreach loop within a List

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, for-loop, foreach

In the below code I am trying to have a session variable that contains a List of strings which holds all of the selected ModuleId's. I am using the module_Changed event to add or remove moduleIDs from this List. Then calling the getModulesAtCurrentSlot in a loop for each moduleid in the list and concatenate the returned string[]s into one longer string[] or List which to display.

I am getting the error "The name 'timeslotInt' and 'Day' does not exist in the current context". The actual getModulesAtCurrentSlot method is located in a separate .cs file so Ive used dba.getModulesAtCurrentSlot... to reference the method but I'm still getting those errors.

.aspx

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="40px"></ItemStyle>
           <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox2" runat="server" ToolTip='<%# Eval("ModuleId") %>' OnCheckedChanged="module_Changed" />
           </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

.cs

```
  protected void module_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> lst;
        if (Session["lst"] != null)
            lst = (List<string>)Session["lst"];
        else
            Session.Add("lst", new List<string>());

        // Retrieve the check box ModuleId value to add to my SELECT query
        string moduleid = ((CheckBox)sender).ToolTip;

        // add your own code to check if checkbox is checked or unchecked to see if you need to add or remove the ID from the list

        // to add
        if (lst.Contains(moduleid) == false)
            lst.Add(moduleid);

        // to remove - add your own code

        int timeslotInt = 0;
        String Day = "text";

        List<string> lstResult = new List<string>();
        foreach (var moduleID in lst)
        { 
          lstResult.Add(dba.getModulesAtCurrentSlot(timeslotInt, module, Day);
        }

        // do something to display lstResult
        Gridview1.DataSource = lstResult;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
    }

}
```

DBAccess.cs

```
   public String[] getModulesAtCurrentSlot(int timeslotInt, String moduleID, String Day)
    {
        List<String> modulesList = new List<string>();
        if (conn.State.ToString() == "Closed")
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        newCmd.Connection = conn;
        newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        newCmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT Module.ModuleCode,ClassType.ClassTypeName,Convert(time,Class.StartTime), Convert(time,Class.EndTime),Building.BuildingName,RoomCode.RoomCode,Class.Color" +
                 " FROM Class INNER JOIN Module ON Class.ModuleId = Module.ModuleId INNER JOIN RoomCode ON Class.RoomCodeId = RoomCode.RoomcodeId INNER JOIN Building ON RoomCode.BuildingId = Building.BuildingId INNER JOIN Days ON Class.DayId = Days.DayID INNER JOIN ClassType ON Class.ClassTypeId = ClassType.ClassTypeId WHERE " +
                                " Module.ModuleId = " + moduleID + " AND Convert(Date,StartTime) = '" + Day + "' AND " + timeslotInt.ToString() + " BETWEEN ClassScheduleStartTimeId and ClassScheduleEndTimeId";
        SqlDataReader dr = newCmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            //Module.ModuleCode,ClassType.ClassTypeName,Convert(time,Class.StartTime), Convert(time,Class.EndTime),Building.BuildingName,RoomCode.RoomCode,Class.Color
            //String current = "<div class='slot'>";
            String current = "<div class='slot' " + (!dr.IsDBNull(6) ? "style=\"background-color: " + dr.GetString(6) + ";\"" : "") + ">";
            current += "<div class='line1'>" + dr.GetString(0) + "&nbsp;" + dr.GetString(1) + "</div>";// +"<br />";
            current += "<div class='line2'>" + dr.GetTimeSpan(2).ToString().TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd(':') + "&nbsp;-&nbsp;" + dr.GetTimeSpan(3).ToString().TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd(':') + "</div>";// +"<br />";
            current += "<div class='line3'>" + dr.GetString(4) + "&nbsp;" + dr.GetString(5) + "</div>";
            current += "</div>";
            modulesList.Add(current);
        }
        conn.Close();
        return modulesList.ToArray();
    }
```

Error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you may be confusing parameter names with variables.

The function `getModulesAtCurrentSlot` takes in three parameters, and you must pass a value for each one. The values you pass need not be variables with the same name as the function parameters, they must only have the same types.

Your function does not define a variable named `timeSlotInt` or `Day`, so you can't use those values.

Comment: Ok thanks. See updated code above. I'm still getting the error. Did I need to define timeslotInt and Day.

Comment: @DavidCraven have you defined the `dba` variable as well? I don't see it in your code. Also, what is the new full error message you are getting?

Comment: At the top of the page I have: using Qsis.App_Code; which contains the cs file 'DBAccess' which contains the getModulesAtCurrentSlot method. The same error message only now 'module' does not exist in the current context. I added in the code for getModulesAtCurrentSlot . :)

Comment: lstResult is `List<string>` and your `getModulesAtCurrentSlot` function returns an `array`. Cast it to `List` and use `AddRange`. For example `lstResult.AddRange((dba.getModulesAtCurrentSlot(timeslotInt, module, Day)).ToList())`